# Database Structure for Multiple Form Checkboxes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, database-design, checkbox

I have a rails app I am working on that allows users to create a schedule.  In doing so, they should be able to select on which days of the week an event occurs.  The way I was planning on doing this in a form was a checkbox next to every, weekday, like so:

```
<%= f.check_box :monday %> <%= f.label :monday %>
<%= f.check_box :tuesday %> <%= f.label :tuesday %>
<%= f.check_box :wednesday %> <%= f.label :wednesday %>
```

etc...

However, It occured to me that this probably isn't a very efficient way of handling this, storing each date as a boolean value in the database.  It will be very difficult to display the dates in the 'show' view; I'll have to do something like

```
Event Dates:
<% if @event.monday? %>
  Monday
<% end %>
<% if @event.tuesday? %>
  Tuesday
<% end %>
<% if @event.wednesday? %>
  Wednesday
<% end %>
```

Which seems less than ideal to me.

My other idea would be to just create one string column in the database that holds all of the event dates, using attr_accesors and a model method to create the string after_create.  However, in this case, how will users be able to edit the Event?

It got me thinking, there must be some sort of best practice here that I don't know about (I've never tried to create something with this type of structure before).

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do this:

> My other idea would be to just create one string column in the database that holds all of the event dates, using attr_accesors and a model method to create the string after_create.

That sort of thing will just cause problems like making per-day queries a horrific ugly mess; how would you, for example, count how many events are available on Monday if you stored your days mashed into a single column?

Instead, keep your seven booleans and add a simple convenience method to your model that returns the days in some more convenient format. Something like this perhaps:

```
def days
  Date::DAYNAMES.map { |d| read_attribute(d.downcase) }
end
```

and then you can simply iterate over `@event.days` in your view and map the day numbers to names:

```
<% @event.days.each_with_index do |on_day, i| %>
  <% if on_day %>
    <%= Date::DAYNAMES[i] %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The specific details of the `days` method and how you deal with it in your ERB will, of course, depend on your specific circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

A detailed better code than the approved one *"In my opinion"* would be:

**Model:**

```
serialize :days

def weekdays
    Date::DAYNAMES.map { |d| d.upcase }
end
```

**View:**

```
<% Model.weekdays.each do |day| %>
   <%= check_box :model, :days, { :multiple => true }, day.downcase, nil %> <%=day.downcase %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Where can I get more information on the "serialize" method for rails models?

Comment: supposing you're saving the *days* array in a :string column type, and in this case the serialize method is needed http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class

Answer (score 0):

```
%{Mon Tue ... Sun}.each_with_index do |day, index| 
  <%= check_box_tag 'name', '1', model.attribute[index].to_i %> 
end
```

Yes workaround but should work

to match records from DB that occur on Sunday

```
Model.where("models.name LIKE '1______'")
```